# If Statement Still Executes when Condition is False

Tags: excel, vba

I have run into an if statement that acts as if it is true even if it evaluates to false, and I cannot figure out what is going on. The code is as follows:

```
If (k = j) Then
    Debug.Print "Code being stupid"
    ReDim pinInfo(UBound(textConn))
    For i = 0 To UBound(textConn)
        For j = 0 To UBound(colConn)
            If (StrComp(textConn(i), colConn(j), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 _
            And StrComp(textPos(i), colPos(j), vbBinaryCompare) = 0) Then
                pinInfo(i) = textConn(i) & "," & textPos(i) & "," & label(i) & "," & colScl(j)
                'Debug.Print pinInfo(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
Else
    Debug.Print "k <> j"
    MsgBox "The number of shapes representing the wire ID does not equal the number of shpaes representing the wire color."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

j and k are both integers. At this point in the program they should always be equal. I intentionally goobered up the input so that they are not, but even though the statement evaluates to false it still acts as if it returned true. The picture below is a screenshot of what I see after execution. As you can see, it shows that the condition is false, yet executes the first print statement and no message box appears.

[image]

Comment: Single '=' mark is a comparison operator?

Comment: Yes in VBA,  it is. `==` is error.

Comment: Just save your workbook. reopen and retry. do you still get this behavior?

Comment: Can you Debug.Print the values of j and k? Although, I really do love, 'Code being stupid'.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try using a different variable name than j? What is j's value prior to the if statement? Is it getting changed after the if statement because of the For Loop? I'd look at that first.

Comment: My thinking is that you broke the code after `j` changes value (in the for loop) and so it is no longer equal to `k`.

Comment: You know, I get this feeling you wouldn't be here with this question if you had `Debug.Print k, j` instead of "Code being stupid"

Comment: Looks like it's true that `k = j` when the `if` statement evaluates it, so it steps into those `for` statements. As @MattCremeens said, in there `j` is modified so it no longer matches up with `k`. Your screenshot only shows you detecting whether `k = j` AFTER the loops run and `j` is changed, not at the time when the `if` is looking at them.

Comment: I think I agree with @Mat's Mug.  Also, when this is all over -- I think you owe your code an apology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `j = k` the `if` block is executed. The debug output is proof of that. At your break point `j` ***is no longer*** equal to `k`.

This is because the already executed `if` block has modified `j` here:

```
For j = 0 To UBound(colConn)
```

After the `if` block the code jumps to the `End If` where you have the break point set. Only then you look at the expression `j = k`, but be aware that since `j` changed in the mean time, this was not the outcome when the `if` statement was executed.

Comment: I would like to take this opportunity to apologize for letting my frustration write the original question. As @Mat's Mug said, it would have been more helpful if I had printed j and k instead of "code being stupid". Had I done that I would have figured out a while ago that wasn't even in this section of code. Sorry for wasting all your time.